# How to get around caption length limit?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

For one of the figures in a Word 2007 document, when I add a long caption (4 lines of text) only the first few lines of text show up in the caption.

I am generating the document from a command-line program based on ActiveX, so am limited in what I can do. Hopefully the caption length is a Word setting that can be changed somehow.
I can't find anything online, but my captions keep getting truncated at about the same point, which makes me think there is a set limit.

How can I make Word accept longer captions without truncating them? Alternatively, if you can point me to some documentation about the caption length limit, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a limitation of the caption size; it's a limitation of the Word object model.  Unfortunately there's not much you can do about it except impersonating the user and inserting text directly.